# Dynamic loading of nginx third party module via chef

Tags: nginx, chef-infra, kerberos, spnego

I am trying to dynamically load a third party module to nginx.

https://github.com/stnoonan/spnego-http-auth-nginx-module

Nginx is installed via package installation using chef recipe.

I have tried compiling the module to module binary .so file and copied it to /etc/nginx/modules directory and added the following line into nginx.conf, but it showed error "unknown directive load_module".

**nginx.conf**

```
load_module modules/ngx_http_auth_spnego_module.so ;
```

**Chef recipe**

```
bash 'create_spnego_module' do
   code <<-EOH
    mkdir -p #{node['nginx']['dir']}/modules
   EOH
 end

cookbook_file "#{node['nginx']['dir']}/modules/ngx_http_auth_spnego_module.so" do
  source 'ngx_http_auth_spnego_module.so'
  owner  'root'
  group  node['root_group']
  mode   '0644'
  notifies :reload, 'service[nginx]', :delayed
end
```

Is there any other way I can load this module via chef without  recompiling nginx source?

Comment: What version of Nginx? Dynamic module loading was added in 2016 so if you're on RHEL or Ubuntu 14.04/16.04 it might be too old.

Comment: @coderanger nginx version is 1.14.0 running on  Ubuntu 14.04.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During compilation of module binary , the configuration arguments for compiling modules should be the same as that of the installed nginx.

Using command line argument  '`nginx -V`' , check the configuration arguments during nginx installation. Use the same arguments during module compilation.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, your version of Nginx is too old for dynamic module loading. You'll either need to recompile it with the new module or install a new version.

Comment: nginx 1.14.0 is the latest stable version I guess. http://nginx.org/en/download.html

Comment: Oh, didn't actually check the version, this is what I get for assuming :) Looks like the feature was specifically added in 1.9. How did you install nginx?

Comment: nginx is installed using package installation via chef nginx cookbook. I created the module binary -  .so  file in Ubuntu 16.04, But my test kitchen VM is provisioned using Ubuntu 14.04 image where nginx is actually getting installed. Does that matter?

Comment: Check that you don't accidentally have things installed via both the Ubuntu and Nginx packages.